# CSV to Feather in Pandas with slicing Rows

Tags: python, pandas, feather

I am processing a huge dataset (50 million rows) in CSV. I am trying to slice it and save it as Feather Format in order to save some memory while loading the feather format later.

As a workaround, I loaded the data in chunks as CSV file and later merged it into one data frame.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
df[2000000:4000000].to_feather('name')
```

I have got the following error:

```
ValueError: feather does not support serializing a non-default index for the index; you can .reset_index() to make the index into column(s)
```

Then I tried to reset the index but still, I get the same error.

Comment: when you reset the index did you add the `inplace=True` argument? You do not actually change your df by doing `df.reset_index()`

Comment: I had the same problem and a reset index fixed it, but as d_kennetz says, you have to either do it in place or assign the result back to your data frame.

Comment: This seems to be like a bug, I would suggest reporting it on github at https://github.com/wesm/feather/issues

Answer (score 5):

Try with `.loc` :

```py
df.loc[2000000:4000000].reset_index().to_feather("./myfeather.ftr")
```

You'll have to reset the indexes to save the datataframe to feather format. Works for me.

Comment: If you don't need to store index you may want to: `reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Save the required slice of the data to CSV `df.to_csv()`, load the data again from the CSV and then save to feather format. This method worked for me

Comment: This seems like a roundabout way to do `df.reset_index()`, it will also take some time for very large dataframes which feather is trying to avoid